# Does Accessibility Inspector work with the tvOS simuator?

Tags: tvos, accessibility-inspector

I'm trying to perform an accessibility audit of a simple Hello World app on tvOS.  When I debug on to a physical Apple TV I can select the device from the dropdown in Accessibility Inspector and then use the inspector view and audit view as expected.

However when I debug onto an Apple TV simulator and select the simulator from the dropdown in Accessibility Inspector, the inspector view doesn't show anything and when I tap the Run Audit button the button becomes disabled but the audit never completes.

Should it be possible to use Accessibility Inspector with the tvOS simulator?  If so, what am I missing?  Any help much appreciated.  Thanks